# Reading session variables after session_write_close

Tags: php, session, frameset

First, my concrete question. Should this work?

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test']='TEST_CONTENT';

    echo '1: ',$_SESSION['test'];
    echo '<br>';

    session_write_close();

    echo '2: ',$_SESSION['test']
?>
```

Now, some background info. We have a web application with a Frameset (don't get me started... no, there's no money to change this) and we found that in some cases our SESSION variables were not being written to the database! After some arduous testing we found that two frames were being loaded concurrently, and while it almost never happens, the first-called frame finished after the second. The first-called frame was overwriting the session with a prior-made copy (since, at the end of script it writes the session).

Our solution now is to try to call session_write_close() on the first-called frame as soon as we can, but we are concerned about being able to still read the session variables (with 100% certainty).

Comment: Why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: Test is, and perphaps you could throw the session variables into a other var (not sure though)

Comment: Can you `session_start` again, right after closing it?

Comment: @DaveChen he didn't close the session, he only writes the session back to register.

Comment: [`End the current session`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php)

Comment: Thanks guys. Obviously I have executed this snipped, and I 'saw that it works'. I am however not so comfortable implementing this in a production environment without being sure that it _should_ work, besides that it does.

As @Bere noted, I don't need to session_start but I also expressly do not want to do this, I want to prevent the writing of the session at the end of this script (say 2s later) so that my other frame can write it (say 1s later) without being overwritten again by the older version.

Dave Chen: what does 'End the current session' mean? Why does my snippet work then?

Comment: @Hendriq I considered this, but it would be convenient not to have to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thinking about it you could implement in a other way.

How to implement it is quiet simple

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = time();
```

This will be put above in your script.

When the script stops it will be saved to your database, but wait stop, we are not done :P

Then you check if the timestamp in the current record is heigher or lower. if it is lower then update, else forget to update and just do nothing. Should consider microtime(). because people love to press f5.

So new idea, and I think it works a little bit better and saver for production to

---

To answer the comment:

Look at [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php), you can make your own function how php handles session. So you don't have to refactor you code, only add.

Then in the write part, you say to the database update the record with id x and where the timestamp is higher then the given value.

For the implementation you should add a column to the record timestamp/mincrotime. And in the session handler you save the time it was request. So you can make the comparison. Then you don't need to save the time in the session either :) (not in the $_SESSION, it is saved in the db!)

Comment: I like this line of reasoning as a work-around. I'm thinking of implementing this idea but not only keeping in mind the current transaction counter // session timestamp, but also checking if the session changed at all during the execution of the complete script.

Any idea how I can do the 'forget to update and just do nothing' part though? As far as I know the session is written automatically after the script ends...